# How to make live connection between two objects

Tags: python

I declare two variables. The first is a dictionary. The second is a list (it is the output of dictionary's '.values()' method).

```
dictVar={'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
listVar=dictVar.values()
```

At this point the content of `listVar` accurately represents every value stored in dictionary `dictVar`
Later somewhere down the code the dictionary is updated with a new value:

```
dictVar['four']=4
```

Now the content of `listVar` is "outdated". It does not represent every value stored in dictionary.
In order to keep list updated I have to manually append a new value such as:

```
dictVar['four']=4
listVar.append(4)
```

I wonder if there is a way to establish a "live" update between the list variable and dictionary. So every time dictionary is changed the list is updated too.

Comment: You could create your own class for the dictionary, overriding the `__setitem__` method so that it automatically updates an associated list.

Comment: Why can't you just use `dictVar.values()` in place of the list, instead of managing two separate objects?

Comment: While working with database I use database's object's ids as dictionary keys. And database objects themselves stored as dictionary values such as: dbDict={1:dbObject1, 2:dbObject2}. But when writing to database a new object doesn't yet have database id (it is not created yet). Yet, the object is already declared. Every object is given `-1` id before it is "really created". So I can't use a dictionary to store the objects reliably since multiple unpublished to db object would have the same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
>>> dictVar={'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
>>> listVar=dictVar.viewvalues()
>>> listVar
dict_values([3, 2, 1])
>>> dictVar['one']=100
>>> listVar
dict_values([3, 2, 100])
>>> dictVar['four']=4
>>> listVar
dict_values([4, 3, 2, 100])
>>> list(listVar)==dictVar.values()
True
```

Comment: Insane how simple it is! Thanks!

Comment: For those like me who's just learned about `.viewvalues()` here is a not: there is a `.viewkeys()` as well! Terrific

Comment: And `.viewitems()` for key, value pairs. Double terrific!

Answer (score 1):

Something you could do would be to create a custom class that acts as a wrapper for the dictionary. Whenever you call `obj[key] = val`, you're implicitly calling that object's `__setitem__(self, key, val)` method. When you create a custom class, you can overwrite this method to do what you like with it (namely, update an associated list).

Here's a sample class wrapper:

```
class EnhancedDict(object):

  def __init__(self):               # The constructor
    self.dictVar = {}           # Your dictionary
    self.listVar = []           # Your list

  def __getitem__(self, key):   # Equivalent to obj[key]
    return self.dictVar[key]

  def __setitem__(self, key, val) # Equivalent to obj[key] = val
    self.dictVar[key] = val
    self.listvar.append(val)
```

Then the list is automatically updated whenever you add a new item to the dictionary, which you can do easily:

```
>>> dict_obj = EnhancedDict()
>>> dict_obj["foo"] = "bar"     # Automatically updates both the list and the dict
>>> dict_obj["foo"]
'bar'
>>> dict_obj.dictVar
{'foo': 'bar'}
>>> dict_obj.listVar
['bar']
```

There's also a `__delitem__` function you can override to complete the functionality of the class. Lots more information can be found in the docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: @Sputnix you're welcome! Also I just fixed a pretty critical typo in `__init__`.